# How to execute (Materialize ) a LINQ query call to a ServiceOperation returning just a string value

Tags: entity-framework, linq-to-entities, wcf-data-services

Up front, the guy on the keyboard here is way overdue on the sleep department. But also kinda desperate.

I have a Data-service [WebGet] method, setup like this.

```
[WebGet]
public string Finalize(string PayloadObject, string CltUUID, string Comment){..}
```

It return a simple string, depending on the outcome of the execution inside. This is working fine.

I call it like this

```
var res = base.ServiceRef.CreateQuery<DBcontext>("Finalize")
.AddQueryOption("PayloadObject", string.Format("'{0}'", builder.ToString()))
...
```

How do I get this query to materialize? 
Usually one uses res.ToList(), ToArray() or .First(). If I do, I get an exception. Using .ToString() does not execute the query, just returns the url.

The query works, if I break in a line after this code and click 'View...' in the debugger, the query is executed, the method runs on the server.

It seems I just don't get it to run, what am I missing?? besides sleep

Thanks for any pointers

Regards, Andreas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you cannot use `CreateQuery` to call operation returning single value. You must use [Execute instead](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh230677.aspx#ExecutePrimitiveValue). MSDN documentation also mentions that operations returning primitive types [cannot use `QueryOption`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668788.aspx) which make sense because query option is used to define query for `IQueryable`. If you need to pass parameters try to use common WCF REST approach to specify template in `WebGet` and on client side use the URI with parameters correctly included.

You can also try to use `SingleResultAttribute` on your service operation.

Comment: Gotten so used to this "Query" way of calling Service-operations, never even thought about the fact it's not a query at all.

Thanks for taking the time to widen my view Ladislav